# Design a LoG (Laplacian of gaussian) $1 \times5$ filter with sigma $=2$

Tags: computer-science, image-processing

Design a LoG (Laplacian of gaussian) $1 \times5$ filter with sigma $=2$.

**Formula to calculate LoG:**

$$\text{LoG}(x,y) \;=\; - \frac1{\pi\sigma^4}\left[1-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

I am given this formula for LoG, however i am not sure how to create a $1 \times5$ filter from this?

Do i just need to plug in $x=1$ and $y=5$?  with sigma 2